# ActiveRecord query too difficult for my tiny brain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have an activerecord model `Event` that I want to order by a rank.  The rank will be a sum of weighted properties.  For instance I might want to rank an event with some logic like:

```
LOG(number of followers) + (7 - number of days from now)
```

The following works, but is not satisfactory because it returns a result set instead of a relation object.  Therefore I won't be able to treat it as a scope. (FYI I am using Postgres with PostGIS extension)

```
x = Event.find_by_sql("
            SELECT   
                (
                    CASE WHEN COUNT(follows.*) = 0 
                    THEN 0 
                    ELSE LOG(COUNT(follows.*)) END

                    +

                    SIGN(7 - (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())) / 86400) * LOG(ABS(7 - (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())) / 86400))
                ) as score,
                events.*
            FROM events
            LEFT OUTER JOIN follows 
                ON events.id = follows.followable_id AND follows.followable_type = 'Event' AND follows.blocked = 'f'
            WHERE (events.start > NOW()) AND (ST_DWithin(st_setsrid(st_point(#{@location[:lng]}, #{@location[:lat]}), 4326), st_transform(loc, 4326), 48280.2, true))
            GROUP BY events.id
            ORDER BY 1 DESC
            ")
```

I understand that I could add a counter cache to the `Events` table and avoid the join, but in the future I will want to compute the rank through some other association so it would be very helpful to know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to split up into `ActiveRecord::Relation` queries.

```
x = Event.select("(
                CASE WHEN COUNT(follows.*) = 0 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE LOG(COUNT(follows.*)) END

                +

                SIGN(7 - (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())) / 86400) * LOG(ABS(7 - (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())) / 86400))
            ) as score,
            events.*")

x = x.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN follows 
            ON events.id = follows.followable_id AND follows.followable_type = 'Event' AND follows.blocked = 'f'")

x = x.where("(events.start > NOW()) AND (ST_DWithin(st_setsrid(st_point(#{@location[:lng]}, #{@location[:lat]}), 4326), st_transform(loc, 4326), 48280.2, true))")

x = x.group('events.id')

x = x.order('1 desc')
```

Of course, I would recommend splitting these up in various scopes, but this should at least get you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this answer your question, but I want to use formatting.

I would make something easier, as I am more comfortable with ruby,I would create a new methods in your Event class:

```
def rank
  # you rank computation according model columns and associations
  Math.log(followers_count) + (7 - number_of_days_from_now)
end

def self.by_rank(order = 'desc')
  all.sort{ |event, event1| order == 'desc' ? event1 <=> event : event <=> event1 }
end
```

Then you can scale caching your computation, creating a rank column in events table, so you can then do something like this:

```
Event.order('rank desc')
Event.order('rank asc')
```